Fantasy novel involving a magic bracelet that saves a man from a fish dinner
I had a vague set of memories pop into my head earlier today. I'm pretty sure it was a fantasy novel from a series I read in my childhood (late 1980s to early 1990s). The scene I remember, I'm pretty sure it was a side character (who presumably later interacted with the main characters). He had wound up with a bracelet (my brain wants to say it had a carved ivory dolphin on it) that gave him a form of uncontrolled precognition. I want to say that he'd only recently acquired the bracelet. Anyhow, he's eating at a tavern, and suddenly has an image of someone nearby him choking to death, which leads him to spring into action, saving the man (and gaining him attention that he really didn't want). As it turned out, the fish the man was eating had a fishhook inside it (I think made out of bone) that the fish had swallowed or otherwise had stuck inside their body.
Unfortunately, outside of that, my brain is failing me. It was definitely a fantasy world like D&D, where magic was common enough that it generally didn't surprise people, but that powerful magic was restricted to a smaller subset of people.

Wanderlust by Steve Winter and Mary Kirchoff, book 2 of the Dragonlance Preludes series.

Tanis Half-Elven now permanently resides in Solace years after his first meeting with Flint Fireforge in Qualinost. A newcomer, the kender, Tasslehoff Burrfoot arrives in Solace and befriends both Tanis and Flint (much to the dwarf's chagrin), after accidentally 'borrowing' a magical bracelet that the dwarf had just made. As the kender leaves town, he again somehow acquires the bracelet and offers it to a tinker, Gaesil, to return it to the dwarf. However the tinker is shortly thereafter fleeced by a con-artist named Delbridge, who claims the magical bracelet for himself.
A Dargonesti elf, named Princess Selana, locates Flint, Tanis and Tas (who has returned to Solace) and requests the magical bracelet that she had the dwarf create for her. Flint tells that the bracelet has been lost and the four journey to Tantallon, after hearing a rumour of the prophet Delbridge who can see the future through use of a magical bracelet. They arrive in Tantallon to find that Delbridge is now a zombie and that the local lord's son, Rostrevor Curston, has disappeared.

The relevant scene:

In his mind Delbridge saw one of the other patrons, a balding, middle-aged gent with arthritic hands, gulping an enormous mouthful of baked trout. Instantly he began choking and gasping for breath. His eyes bulged out, his hands circled his own throat, and his tongue swelled obscenely until, within moments, he fell from his bench to the floor. There he kicked and squirmed several moment more before lying still.

....

The man looked to his companions for support of some sort, then shrugged and picked up the dropped fork. He used it to poke through the crumbling meat on the table and within seconds found something. With his fingers he picked out a sliver of bone about as long as his fingernail, shaped and sharpened to a point. It was a broken bit of a handmade fish hook. With a look of amazement, the customer held it out in his palm for all to see.

I was wrong about the description of the bracelet:

The copper bracelet had an exquisite simplicity that the kender found most appealing. And he was very happy to discover four semiprecious stones, just as he'd suspected. Better yet, they were odd stones, of a variety he'd not seen before. Their color was pale amber. Each was a slightly different shape, but no more than a quarter-inch in diameter. The bracelet was quite small, not meant for a human's or dwarf's thick wrist. Slipping it over his hand, he was delighted to see that it fit perfectly and was as light as a feather.

The reason I was thinking of a dolphin is that the bracelet was commissioned by Selana Sonluanaau, a Dargonesti elf who can turn into a dolphin. She'd commissioned the bracelet to help her brother Semunel become Speaker of the Moon, which required him to be able to look into the future. I had an idea in the back of my head that it might be a Dragonlance book, even though nothing specifically pointed to it and I couldn't remember any characters from that series being part of it, so I started doing some idle searches, which turned up that Flint had been commissioned to make a bracelet for the sea elves (which matched the dolphin part), which led to me trying to figure out which book that was, which led me to Wanderlust.
